# Bit masking model attributes: Yeah or Nay?

Tags: database, module, model

I would like to know if bit masking a attribute in a model is good practice. To me it makes sense: Low database usage and fast extraction of the data. Maybe I'm overseeing something, so I would like to know your opinion!

```
<?php

class Test_Module_Model_Slider extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {


  const TEMPLATE_DEFAULT = 0;
  const TEMPLATE_TWO_AT_ONCE = 1;

  const NAVIGATION_BULLETS_ENABLED = 0;
  const NAVIGATION_ARROWS_ENABLED = 2;
  const NAVIGATION_ARROWS_HIDE_AUTO = 4;
  const NAVIGATION_ARROWS_REMOVE_ON_TOUCH = 8;

  protected $_eventPrefix = 'test_module_slider';

  protected $_eventObject = 'slider';
  protected $_slides = array();
  protected $navigationOptions = 0;

  public function _construct() {
    $this->_init('test_module/slider');
  }

  public function getSlideCollection() {
    $slideCollection = Mage::getModel('test_module/slide')->getCollection();
    $slideCollection->addFilter('slider_id', $this->getId());
    return $slideCollection;
  }

  public function setBulletsEnabled($value) {
    $this->setNavigationOption(self::NAVIGATION_BULLETS_ENABLED, $value);
  }

  public function getBulletsEnabled() {
    return $this->getNavigationOption(self::NAVIGATION_BULLETS_ENABLED);
  }

  public function setArrowsEnabled($value) {
    $this->setNavigationOption(self::NAVIGATION_ARROWS_ENABLED, $value);
  }

  public function getArrowsEnabled() {
    return $this->getNavigationOption(self::NAVIGATION_ARROWS_ENABLED);
  }

  public function setArrowsHideAuto($value) {
    $this->setNavigationOption(self::NAVIGATION_ARROWS_HIDE_AUTO, $value);
  }

  public function getArrowsHideAuto() {
    return $this->getNavigationOption(self::NAVIGATION_ARROWS_HIDE_AUTO);
  }

  public function setArrowsRemoveOnTouch($value) {
    $this->setNavigationOption(self::NAVIGATION_ARROWS_REMOVE_ON_TOUCH, $value);
  }

  public function getArrowsRemoveOnTouch() {
    return $this->getNavigationOption(self::NAVIGATION_ARROWS_REMOVE_ON_TOUCH);
  }

  protected function setNavigationOption($option, $value) {
    if ($value) {
        $this->navigationOptions = $this->navigationOptions | $option;
    } else {
        $this->navigationOptions = $this->navigationOptions & ~$option;
    }
  }

  public function getNavigationOption($option) {
    return (($this->navigationOptions & $option) != 0);
  }

}
```